# Make: execute 2nd rule only if 1st changed file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Consider the following `make` workflow, in which I (a) want to be sure to always work on the newest `download.zip` file, but (b) only run the rest of the workflow when this file changes:

```
my_output.file: download.zip
    some_expensive_operation

download.zip:
    wget -N http://some.server/download.zip
```

In this example, `wget` has got dependency information that `make` does not have.

If `download.zip` is present, the rule will never be executed and `wget` will never check if there is a newer file available.

I can of course make `.PHONY: download.zip` to have the rule executed every time, by then `some_expensive_operation` will be executed as well **no matter** if the file changed or not.

Is there any way to tell `make` to run the `my_output.file` rule above only if `download.zip` *actually* changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the force rule trick:

```
my_output.file: download.zip
        some_expensive_operation

download.zip: FORCE
        wget -N http://some.server/download.zip

FORCE: ;
```

(or you could declare `.PHONY: FORCE` if you prefer).  This ensures that the recipe for `download.zip` is always run, but it's not marked phony itself so targets that depend on it won't be rebuilt unless it's changed.

Comment: No. The [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Force-Targets.html) states that "all targets depending on this one will always have their recipe run".

Comment: Believe me, it works.  Did you try it?  The documentation is correct: the target depending on `FORCE` (the `download.zip` target) _does_ always have its recipe run; my understanding is that's what you want.  But if the `download.zip` file timestamp doesn't change then `my_output.file` is not considered out of date, and `some_expensive_operation` is not run.  Note `my_output.file` doesn't depend on `FORCE`, so that statement in the documentation doesn't apply to that target.

Comment: IIRC last time I tried I observed all targets that depend on a `.PHONY` target always being rebuilt. - I'll check again.

Comment: I reiterate: it's true that targets that depend on `.PHONY` targets are always rebuilt.  But it's _not_ true that targets that depend on (non-phony) targets that depend on `.PHONY` targets are always rebuilt.  In my example, `my_output.file` does not depend on a `.PHONY` target, because `download.zip` is not phony.  So `my_output.file` is not always rebuilt; it uses normal out-of-date semantics.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just tested and the way you set it up works.